# Export value from nvarchar datatype column that saved like xml format

Tags: sql-server

I want to export value from `nvarchar` datatype column that saved like xml format.

The `nvarchar` column value looks like this:

```
<TablePhoneHome><Number Num="1111"/></TablePhoneHome>
```

I want to export `1111` from that

Thanks

Comment: please give us more information.
all of values has same xml format?

Comment: if all of the values is same xml format, you can use `REPLACE()` function in sql-server.

Have you tried this?

Comment: If it's XML, why are you not using the `xml` data type; then this is trivial with XQUERY.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is XML, you should really be using the `xml` data type, then this is trivial. I use `CONVERT` here, but you should really fix the data type in your table.

```
CONVERT(xml, YourColumn).value('(TablePhoneHome/Number/@Num)[1]','int')
```

Like I said though, really you should change your table's column data type:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (YourColumn nvarchar(MAX));

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES('<TablePhoneHome><Number Num="1111"/></TablePhoneHome>');

ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn xml;

SELECT YourColumn.value('(TablePhoneHome/Number/@Num)[1]','int') AS Num
FROM YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=750228b3c69e7b4a5c3f9c7de1e1134e)